# Complex Destructuring: Object inside first index of Array that is inside another Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Consider this 'complex' object:

```
const obj = {
    nestedArray: [
        { stuff: "things" }
    ],
    nestedObj: {
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2"
    }
}
```

I'm looking for an elegant one-line solution to destructure `key1`, `key2`, and `stuff` from `obj`.

My current solution looks like this and works just fine:

```
const { nestedArray, nestedObj: { key1, key2 } } = obj
const { stuff } = nestedArray[0]
```

But I would rather do it in one line like this:

```
const { array[0]: { stuff }, nestedObject: { key1, key2 } } = obj
```

But clearly that will not work.  Any way of doing this in one line like I want?  Or am I asking too much of ES6?  I'd be more than happy to accept an answer of "no" as long is it provides a nice explanation as to why not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close, just use array destructuring with object destructuring to get `stuff`:

```js
const obj = {
    nestedArray: [
        { stuff: "things" }
    ],
    nestedObj: {
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2"
    }
}

const { nestedArray: [{ stuff }], nestedObj: { key1, key2 } } = obj

console.log({ stuff, key1, key2 })
```

Comment: Thank you.  I knew I was missing something.  Will this still work if `nestedArray` has more than one object inside of it?  Will I still get index 0 every time?  Assuming that the other object in the array has the same key?

Comment: @PsiKai Yes. It only doesn't work if `nestedArray` is not iterable or empty.

Comment: It will only work on the object in index 0, even if there are multiple objects. You will get only 1 `stuff` value.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for the warning, luckily I have this destructuring inside a `trycatch` block so any issue will trigger the error state.

Comment: @OriDrori Thank you, that can be a little confusing at times.  So really, naming it `stuff` in the destructuring is arbitrary and I can call it whatever I want, not just the given key name (which is how array destructuring works of course).

Comment: Array destructuring is arbitrary, but object desturcturing is not, so you can't have multiple `stuff` variables. However, you can use aliasing `[{ stuff: s1 }, { stuff: s2 }, ...]`. However, if you got to this point, destructuring is probably not the way to go, and you should use `Array.map()` to get an array of `stuff` values.

Answer (score 5):

While it's *possible*, by listing `stuff` as its position in the nested array, very similar to if you were declaring an array with an object with the `stuff` property:

```js
const obj = {
    nestedArray: [
        { stuff: "things" }
    ],
    nestedObj: {
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2"
    }
};
const { nestedArray: [{ stuff }], nestedObj: { key1, key2 } } = obj;
console.log(stuff);
```

I wouldn't recommend it - code like this gets very hard to read.

Comment: Thank you for the word of warning.  I don't plan on this destructuring getting any more complicated than it is, or else I would take more care to keep it readable.  This was more of a learning exercise for me and I can envision other use cases that aren't as confusing to read :)